# How can I transport a wolf over water.

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently found wolves on an island and tamed several, however I am unable to bring any of them back to my base which is separated from this island by water. How can I get a wolf back to my base over water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that it was possible to get a wolf to sit in a boat, and you can then get in the boat and row your wolf across the water. I didn't know boats could fit 2.

Answer (score 3):

### There are a bunch of ways

- **Nether route**: build a portal at your base, and another on the island. Push or lead the dogs through, and transport them through netherrack tunnels.
- **Bridge**: build a 1-block wide bridge across the ocean at water level. Lead the wolf across it.
- **Boat**: You can sit in a boat with another entity. Push the wolf in, and row back home.
- **Teleportation**: Tamed wolves should eventually teleport back to you. If  not, consider restarting the game, punching the wolves a bit, etc.
- **Commands**: As a last-resort option, use the following steps:

  - 1. Push all the wolves into a small room
  - 2. Go to the esc menu => `Open to Lan` => `Allow Cheats` => `On`
  - 3. Standing next to the room with the wolves, run the following command: `/tp @e[r=3,type=Wolf] coordinates` where `coordinates` is replaced with the x, y, and z of a safe place in your house

Answer (score 2):

Since tamed wolves teleport to your after you walk far away from them, try going to base while ignoring the tamed wolf. When you reach the base, your wolf will teleport to where you are.

Comment: Teleportation didn't work for me, perhaps it has something to with spawn chunks or something

Answer (score 1):

Last time I had to do something like this, I brought them back to base through the Nether, just by building portals both places.

Answer (score 1):

You just have the wolf sit down, and then have a mob damage you when you're home. They should come to your aid: they'll stand up (teleport to you) and attack the mob that attacked you.

Answer (score 0):

Have your dog set to "follow me" take a lead and attach it to them. After that, hop in a boat and sail back, they'll be dragged behind. Don't worry, they won't drown or get hurt, I do this all the time. Remember, this will NOT work if your dog is sitting.

Or, if it's a creative world, put a leash on your dog, make sure they aren't sitting, and fly home. They'll be dragged behind.