# How far away can I be from tamed pets before they stop teleporting to me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've established a small base on an island where wolves and cats do not spawn. If I want to tame a wolf I'll need to take a boat on a long journey to a forest and wait one to spawn. I could load my soon-to-be-tamed-wolf in a boat, but that would mean I'd have to make another long trip if I wanted a second pet.

Normally, when I do this I'd feel comfortable swimming or walking back to my house because it's so close but this excursion is large enough I'd want to rely on the teleporting mechanics to make it easier.

How far away can I get from a tamed pet before it stops teleporting to me? Will the wolf, who can't swim as the fast as I can operate the boat, teleport to me when I return to my island?

Comment: Probably it needs to be lloaded

Comment: Seriously consider the Nether. In particular making the Nether ceiling accessible and utilizing it for fast, long-distance travel.

Comment: Of course, I'm very comfortable using the Nether for transport, but  I like knowing about all the options that are available for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pets will only teleport to you when the chunk they are in is loaded. See [the wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf#Teleportation) for more information.

As SF said, the fastest way is probably the nether; there are plenty of online guides on how to move pets through it. See [this answer on viable ways to transport a wolf via water.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/297360/261322)